# When implementing reverse infinite scrolling and wanting to keep the scroll position fixed when loading new data, how should it be done

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intersection-observer

I would like to create something like the following example.
[see example](https://better-react-infinite-scroll.vercel.app/)
[see example code](https://github.com/Apestein/better-react-infinite-scroll)

The following two codes are my reverse infinite scroll code. When you run this code, it will appear as shown in the video below. The recognition of the top works well for loading new data, but the mouse scroll remains fixed at the top.

As intended, when you bring the scroll to the top like in the link below, new data should be loaded, and the scroll should adjust to the current viewing position.

What could be the issue? In the correct example code, the scroll automatically stays fixed to the item currently being viewed even without explicitly specifying the scroll position. Why does my code move from the currently viewed item to the newly refreshed item?

following video file show How the problem looks like
https://github.com/Gaepo-transcendance-fighters/FRONT-END/assets/87654307/cda09767-16df-4bcc-ad87-996c1f6662a6

The data coming from the server is in the following format.

```
[
  { channelIdx: 1, sender: 'wochae', msg: 'channelIdx 1, msg 71' },
  { channelIdx: 1, sender: 'jujeon', msg: 'channelIdx 1, msg 72' },
  { channelIdx: 1, sender: 'jaekim', msg: 'channelIdx 1, msg 73' },
  { channelIdx: 1, sender: 'haryu', msg: 'channelIdx 1, msg 74' },
  { channelIdx: 1, sender: 'wochae', msg: 'channelIdx 1, msg 75' }
]
```

My code is down below

```
// App.js
import Chats2 from "./Chats2";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        width: "50%",
        height: "500px",
        margin: "auto",
        backgroundColor: "purple",
        overflow: "auto",
        
      }}
    >
      <h1>Inverse Scroll</h1>
      <Chats2 />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
// Chats2.js
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState, useRef, useCallback } from "react";

const TOTAL_PAGES = 100;

const options = {
  threshold: 0.1,
};

const Chats = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [pageNum, setPageNum] = useState(0);

  const [chats, setChats] = useState([]);

  const observerTarget = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => {
        if (entries[0]?.isIntersecting) {
          setPageNum((num) => num + 1)
        }
      }, options)
  
    if (observerTarget.current) {
      observer.observe(observerTarget.current)
    }

    return () => {
      if (observerTarget.current) {
        observer.unobserve(observerTarget.current)
      }
    }
    }, [observerTarget])


  const callUser = useCallback(async () => {
    console.log(pageNum);
    await axios
      .get(`http://localhost:4000/chat/messages?channelIdx=1&index=${pageNum}`)
      .then((res) => {
        const newData = Array.isArray(res.data) ? res.data : [res.data];
        setChats((prevChats) => [...prevChats, ...newData]);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, [pageNum]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (pageNum <= TOTAL_PAGES) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        callUser();
      }, 500);
      setLoading(true);
    }
  }, [pageNum]);

  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column-reverse",
          overflow: "auto",
          overflowAnchor: "none",
          position: "sticky",
          overflowAnchor: "none", 
        }}
      >
        {chats.map((chats, i) => {
          return (
            <div
            key={i}
            style={{
              height: "100px",
            }}
            >
              <li>{chats.sender}</li>
              <li>{chats.msg}</li>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <div ref={observerTarget}></div>
        {loading === true && <p>loading...</p>}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Chats;
```

Comparing it to the example GitHub code I attached at the very top, it's not significantly different, so I'm not sure why it's not working. Please help me figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

Here are the styles applied to the `div` holding the chat messages and the `div` holding that `div`:

```
// div holding chat messages

display: "flex",
flexDirection: "column-reverse",
overflow: "auto",
overflowAnchor: "none",
position: "sticky",
```

```
// div holding the div holding the chat messages

width: "50%",
height: "500px",
margin: "auto",
backgroundColor: "purple",
overflow: "auto",
```

The `div` holding the chat messages does not have a `height` specified. As a result it grows to overflow its parent, giving its parent a scrollbar. However, the `overflow-anchor` for the parent is `auto` (the default value as it hasn't been explicitly set) so the scroll position appears to change as the overflow grows.

## Solution

You need to ensure the `div` holding the chat messages does not overflow its parent. You could do this by doing one of the following:

- Giving it a `height`.
- Setting its parent `display` to `flex` and `flex-direction` of `column` and setting its `flex-grow` to `1`, `flex-shrink` to `1` and `flex-basis` to `0%`.

### Height demo

```js
const { Fragment, StrictMode, useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } = React;
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;

const TOTAL_PAGES = 100;

const options = {
  threshold: 0.1,
};

const Chats2 = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [pageNum, setPageNum] = useState(0);

  const [chats, setChats] = useState([]);

  const observerTarget = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => {
        if (entries[0] && entries[0].isIntersecting) {
          setPageNum((num) => num + 1)
        }
      }, options)
  
    if (observerTarget.current) {
      observer.observe(observerTarget.current)
    }

    return () => {
      if (observerTarget.current) {
        observer.unobserve(observerTarget.current)
      }
    }
  }, [observerTarget.current]);
  
  const callUser = useCallback(() => {
    // Simulate new data
    setTimeout(() => {
      const newData = [
        { channelIdx: 1, sender: 'wochae', msg: `channelIdx 1, msg ${pageNum * 5 + 1}` },
        { channelIdx: 1, sender: 'jujeon', msg: `channelIdx 1, msg ${pageNum * 5 + 2}` },
        { channelIdx: 1, sender: 'jaekim', msg: `channelIdx 1, msg ${pageNum * 5 + 3}` },
        { channelIdx: 1, sender: 'haryu', msg: `channelIdx 1, msg ${pageNum * 5 + 4}` },
        { channelIdx: 1, sender: 'wochae', msg: `channelIdx 1, msg ${pageNum * 5 + 5}` }
      ];
      setChats((prevChats) => [...prevChats, ...newData]);
      setLoading(false);
    }, 300);
  }, [pageNum]);


//  const callUser = useCallback(async () => {
//    console.log(pageNum);
//    await axios
//      .get(`http://localhost:4000/chat/messages?channelIdx=1&index=${pageNum}`)
//      .then((res) => {
//        const newData = Array.isArray(res.data) ? res.data : [res.data];
//        setChats((prevChats) => [...prevChats, ...newData]);
//        setLoading(false);
//  });
//  }, [pageNum]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (pageNum <= TOTAL_PAGES) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        callUser();
      }, 500);
      setLoading(true);
    }
  }, [pageNum]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          height: "300px",
          flexDirection: "column-reverse",
          overflow: "auto",
          overflowAnchor: "none",
          position: "sticky",
        }}
      >
        {chats.map((chats, i) => {
          return (
            <div
            key={i}
            style={{
              height: "100px",
            }}
            >
              <li>{chats.sender}</li>
              <li>{chats.msg}</li>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <div ref={observerTarget}></div>
        {loading === true && <p>loading...</p>}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        width: "50%",
        height: "500px",
        margin: "auto",
        backgroundColor: "purple",
        overflow: "auto",
      }}
    >
      <h1>Inverse Scroll</h1>
      <Chats2 />
    </div>
  );
};

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<StrictMode><App /></StrictMode>);
```

```css
html, body, #root {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

### Flex demo

```js
const { Fragment, StrictMode, useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } = React;
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;

const TOTAL_PAGES = 100;

const options = {
  threshold: 0.1,
};

const Chats2 = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [pageNum, setPageNum] = useState(0);

  const [chats, setChats] = useState([]);

  const observerTarget = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => {
        if (entries[0] && entries[0].isIntersecting) {
          setPageNum((num) => num + 1)
        }
      }, options)
  
    if (observerTarget.current) {
      observer.observe(observerTarget.current)
    }

    return () => {
      if (observerTarget.current) {
        observer.unobserve(observerTarget.current)
      }
    }
  }, [observerTarget.current]);
  
  const callUser = useCallback(() => {
    // Simulate new data
    setTimeout(() => {
      const newData = [
        { channelIdx: 1, sender: 'wochae', msg: `channelIdx 1, msg ${pageNum * 5 + 1}` },
        { channelIdx: 1, sender: 'jujeon', msg: `channelIdx 1, msg ${pageNum * 5 + 2}` },
        { channelIdx: 1, sender: 'jaekim', msg: `channelIdx 1, msg ${pageNum * 5 + 3}` },
        { channelIdx: 1, sender: 'haryu', msg: `channelIdx 1, msg ${pageNum * 5 + 4}` },
        { channelIdx: 1, sender: 'wochae', msg: `channelIdx 1, msg ${pageNum * 5 + 5}` }
      ];
      setChats((prevChats) => [...prevChats, ...newData]);
      setLoading(false);
    }, 300);
  }, [pageNum]);


//  const callUser = useCallback(async () => {
//    console.log(pageNum);
//    await axios
//      .get(`http://localhost:4000/chat/messages?channelIdx=1&index=${pageNum}`)
//      .then((res) => {
//        const newData = Array.isArray(res.data) ? res.data : [res.data];
//        setChats((prevChats) => [...prevChats, ...newData]);
//        setLoading(false);
//  });
//  }, [pageNum]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (pageNum <= TOTAL_PAGES) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        callUser();
      }, 500);
      setLoading(true);
    }
  }, [pageNum]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column-reverse",
          overflow: "auto",
          overflowAnchor: "none",
          position: "sticky",
          flex: "1 1 0%"
        }}
      >
        {chats.map((chats, i) => {
          return (
            <div
            key={i}
            style={{
              height: "100px",
            }}
            >
              <li>{chats.sender}</li>
              <li>{chats.msg}</li>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <div ref={observerTarget}></div>
        {loading === true && <p>loading...</p>}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        width: "50%",
        height: "100%",
        margin: "auto",
        backgroundColor: "purple",
        overflow: "auto",
      }}
    >
      <h1>Inverse Scroll</h1>
      <Chats2 />
    </div>
  );
};

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<StrictMode><App /></StrictMode>);
```

```css
html, body, #root {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thank you so much. I got fixed it. only thing I done is adding height at parent div... you save my life. I have been struggle for two days